# "More Communities" list magnifying-glass icon doesn't disappear when searching Area 51 and Network Chat

Tags: bug, search, area-51, communities-list

On [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com), I clicked the "More Stack Exchange communities" to return to [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com), and noticed that the "magnifying-glass" icon in the "More Communities" list, was pasted *over* the word "find", instead of prepending the word, as with the other sites:

[image]

The icon also remains when the site name is typed in:

[image]

Which hinders reading and just looks bad.  Can this please be fixed?

---

**UPDATE**

This also happens when searching the same area in the [Stack Exchange Network chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/).